# ESLint not showing up in VScode

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

This might be a very silly question, but I installed ESLint and it's not showing up on the bottom of my VSCode window. Am I doing something wrong?

[image: My VSCode]

Comment: Did you run the command `Create ESLint configuration` defined [in their GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint)?

Comment: @Das_Geek I'm using an eslintrc.json from my node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

Nope, as long as you install ESLint correctly, it's fine. (It doesn't show up on the bar at the bottom).